# Material Rendering background

Tags: materials

I'm doing an animation in wich I have and hdri as a background and one of the objects I have is a water bottle, so it's supposed to be transparent. The problem of it being transparent is that it's rendering with the background image wich I didn't want to happen. Is there any way i can fix it?